# Manim Error TypeError: Graph.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given or Graph.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, error-handling, manim

I have some really strange issue with manim package. Running an example code from the page of `Manim community` for `Graphs` always returns an error.

```
class LabeledModifiedGraph(Scene):

    def construct(self):
        vertices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        edges = [(1, 2), (3,1), (1,3), (1,4), (2,1), (2, 3), (2, 5),
                 (3, 4),(4,2), (5,3), (4,5)]
        g = Graph(vertices, edges,  layout="circular", layout_scale=3,
                  labels=True, vertex_config={4: {"fill_color": RED}},
                  edge_config={(1, 2): {"stroke_color": RED},
                               (2, 3): {"stroke_color": RED},
                               (3, 4): {"stroke_color": RED}})
        self.play(Create(g))
        self.add(g)
```

And though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\manimlib\extract_scene.py", line 155, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.construct()
  File "C:\Users\Ann\Desktop\projektarbeit\pagerank.py", line 44, in construct    
    g = Graph(vertices, edges,  layout="circular", layout_scale=3,
TypeError: Graph.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'layout
```

Or if try some other examples of animating/representing graphs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\manimlib\extract_scene.py", line 155, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.construct()
  File "C:\Users\Ann\Desktop\projektarbeit\pagerank.py", line 150, in construct   
    g = Graph(vertices, edges)
TypeError: Graph.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

I would be really grateful for your help!

Comment: you could add link to this example

Comment: there are two versions of `Manim` - [Manim community](https://www.manim.community/) and original [Manim created by 3b1b](https://github.com/3b1b/manim). They may work in different way. Maybe you use example with wrong version.

Comment: I don't see `edge_type` in your code - maybe you run different code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: code works for me with `Manim community  v0.15.1`

Comment: https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.graph.Graph.html# That was the page, where got the the code

Comment: The thing is, that when I tried it out yesterday it was still working. And today, even though I didn't change anything (at least consciously), I got an error.

Comment: but it seems it use wrong `manim`. When I run `manin -pql main.py LabeledModifiedGraph` then I see `Manim Community v0.15.2` and I know that I use correct version. But know I see your path in error message and it has `/manimlib/` which can means different `Manim`

Comment: when I check `import manim` and `print( manim.__file__ )` then I see it has path with `/manim/` - so you use wrong version on `manim`

Comment: I see the right version if I run it:  'manim -pqm C:\Users\Ann\Desktop\projektarbeit\pagerank.py LabeledModifiedGraph
Manim Community v0.15.2'

Comment: do you get error when you run this way? Error shows that it runs `manimlib` instead of `manim`. How did you run code when you get error?

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code, so I first run a code with F5 or with the button 'Run the code' and after in the Terminal  `manim -pqm C:\Users\Ann\Desktop\projektarbeit\pagerank.py RandomWebGraph`  , for both of the cases I get `Manim Community v0.15.2`

Comment: I still get an error

Comment: However again only for these Graph applications, all the other stuff, like displaying text works perfectly well

Comment: it is strange - it looks like some mess in code - maybe you should first unsintall all manin versions and later install only `manim community`.

Comment: Well, I have just found out one thing. I have two different Manims (manim and then manimlib), saved in different places, probably that is the issue. I appreciate your help! And have a lovely weekend!